# Prove True or false

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

if the rref of a has a row of 0', then the set of row vectors of a is linearly dependent. Please help me prove or give a counterexample

Answer (score 0):

It is true. You try to give a proof using the fact that reducing by rows a matrix is, in fact, a process that applies linear combinations of the same rows of the matrix to other row(s), so if at some point a row becomes all zeros that means that row is a linear combination of the other ones.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, thats what I had in mind too and wrote on paper, however some friend of mine told me that he proved it wrong by a counterexample, do u think if there is any possibilies of that or should I just go with true?

Comment: If you already have **a proof** then your friend is obviously wrong (and he is). It'd be interesting though to read his "counter example"...and find the mistake.

Comment: For clarification, in case this is your friend's counter example, the set of vectors $\{0, v_2, v_3, \cdots, v_n\}$ is said to be linearly *dependent* since $0 = 1\cdot 0 + 0\cdot v_2 + 0\cdot v_3 +\cdots + 0\cdot v_n$.  A set of linearly dependent vectors is one such that you can express 0 as $c_1\cdot v_1 + c_2\cdot v_2 +\cdots$ where at least one of $c_i\neq 0$.  For the case of the zero vector being $v_i$ you can set $c_i\neq 0$.